# A table bug I just encountered

Tags: bug, markdown

I was trying to make a liar puzzle.

This is what it looked like in the preview thing in the edit mode,

[image]

Then, this is what it looked like in question.

[image]

Is this a problem with my device or the site?

Comment: Several "broken markdown" issues can be fixed by putting some newlines around (before AND after) the broken thing. But I guess it's worth to bring this to Meta SE.

Comment: Indeed. (I've edited the question to add some extra newlines, and it did fix the problem.) It seems super-weird that it works in preview and fails once actually posted.

Comment: Thanks! @Bubbler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357596)

> If you have text right above or below the table, the preview renders the table markdown as a table. But after you save the post, the table is not rendered and just shows the markdown code.

The rest of that answer is a demonstration of the bug.